# Derivative $\|\operatorname{diag}(X^T A X) - y\|^2_2$ with respect to $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to take the derivative of $\|\operatorname{diag}(X^T A X) - y\|^2_2$ with respect to $A$,

where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the vector 
$$w={\rm diag}(X^TAX)-y$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable, then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= w:w \cr
d\phi &= 2w:dw \cr
 &= 2w:{\rm diag}(X^T\,dA\,X) \cr
 &= 2\,{\rm Diag}(w):(X^T\,dA\,X) \cr
 &= 2X\,{\rm Diag}(w)\,X^T:dA \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A} &= 2X\,{\rm Diag}(w)\,X^T \cr
}$$
where $\,\odot$ represents the elementwise/Hadamard product

while a $\,:$ represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

The function $\,{\rm Diag}(a)\,$ creates a diagonal matrix from the input vector, while 
$\,{\rm diag}(A)\,$ does the opposite, i.e. it creates a vector from the diagonal of the input matrix.