# Solving Quadratic Matrix Programming (Trace of a Vector Multiplication) with Boundary Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I intend to solve for vector $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1} $ by solving the following optimization problem

\begin{align}
\arg \min_{x} Tr( (\mathbf{K} \mathbf{W})^T \mathbf{P} ( \mathbf{K} \mathbf{W})) - 2Tr( \mathbf{P} \mathbf{K} \mathbf{W})
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{subject to } & x_{i}^{min} \leq x_{i} \leq x_{i}^{max} \\ 
\end{align}
where $Tr()$ is the trace operator, $\mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$, $\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{A}diag(\mathbf{B} x)$, and  $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times M}$, and $\mathbf{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times D}$.

$\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times M}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ are both positive metrices.

How do I solve it as an inequality constrained optimization problem for $X$ ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not directly related to signal processing. It's about optimization and should probably be asked on math.SE.

Comment: If $ A $ is invertible then once you solved for $ A X $ you solved for $ X $. The questions is, what do you know about $ A $?

Comment: thanks for your answer @Royi. you may be surprised that I was hoping you answer my question because I saw similar problems solved by you here in stack exchange. actually, I don't have problem finding $\mathbf{X}$ from $\mathbf{AX}$. my main challenge is which constraints should I apply to the above problem. does $\mathbf{X}_{ik}^{min}<\mathbf{X}_{ik}<\mathbf{X}_{ik}^{max}$ mean that $\mathbf{lb}_{ik}<\mathbf{AX}_{ik}<\mathbf{ub}_{ik}$ ? in other words, if $\mathbf{X}$ is bounded, does it mean that $\mathbf{AX}$ is bounded as well?

Comment: I am not so sure I understood your question.

Comment: lets look at this problem. if I have a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ in which each element is bounded between a minimum and maximum( $\mathbf{X}_{ik}^{min}<\mathbf{X}_{ik}<\mathbf{X}_{ik}^{max}$). Can I say that each element of $\mathbf{AX}$ has mimum and maximum? if this is not correct, so I can not find $\mathbf{X}$ by simply taking the inverse of $\mathbf{A}$ and multiply it by the solution.

Comment: I think you better just write the whole problem you have. With all constraints and let us come up with a way to solve it.

Comment: @MahshadJavidan, Could you edit the question with its full form? It will assist us to solve it. Maybe it can be directly solved for $ X $.

Comment: @Royi, Yes you are right. I think that's a better idea to put the full form of question with all the constraints. I will edit the above question just right now. Thanks.

Comment: In order to make it convex problem you must have $ {x}_{i}^{min} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {x}_{i}^{max} $. If so, please edit. Also, no need to `\mathbf` for matrices. Usually Matrices are capital letters and vectors are small letters.

Comment: @Royi, thanks for mentioning that. I corrected the constraint to be convex.

Comment: @MahshadJavidan, Can you share what you did?

Comment: @Royi I posted Matrix Calculus to find the gradient. I appreciate if you check my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \operatorname{Tr} \left( {\left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right)}^{T} \left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) \right) - 2 \operatorname{Tr} \left( P K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {a}_{i} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {b}_{i} \; \forall i
\end{aligned}$$

The problem here is the $ \operatorname{diag} \left( \cdot \right) $ operator which makes it hard to infer the gradient.

Yet:

$$ \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) = I \circ \left( \boldsymbol{1} {\left( B x \right)}^{T} \right) = I \circ \left( \boldsymbol{1} {x}^{T} {B}^{T} \right) $$

Where $ \circ $ is the [Hadamard Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Now you can plug it in and use some Matrix Calculus to find the gradient (It seems that using the [Frobenius Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) will be useful).
Once you have the gradient you can solve it easily with Projected Gradient Descent Method.

Probably due to use of the [Trace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) you can get better equivalent forms of the problem that takes advantage of $ A $ and $ B $ being Positive definite matrices. As since they are solving for $ y = B x $ is like solving for $ x $.

**Remark**:

I think the question: Given $ y = A x $ where $ A $ is PD matrix and it is known that $ {a}_{i} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {b}_{i} $ what can be said on $ y $ (Namley how it is bounded) deserves its own question.

### Update

Thinking of it, one could calculate the gradient of the Frobenius norm directly:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right\|}_{F}^{2} = {B}^{T} \operatorname{diag} \left( {A}^{T} A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) $$

Comment: thank you for such a useful explanations. it really helped me to find the right direction. actually, I used the Frobenius product properties to find the gradient with respect to $x$ and then I applied the projected gradient descent to find the solution. in fact I'm not completely sure about my calculations and Matlab implementation. here is my email address: mahshad.javidan@gmail.com I really appreciate if you can send me an email so that I can share my notes with you to make sure they are correct.

Comment: You can share what you did in the question and I will address it.

Comment: Some tricks related to `diag()` derivative: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978183, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393883, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611248.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is given by:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \operatorname{Tr} \left( {\left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right)}^{T} P \left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) \right) - 2 \operatorname{Tr} \left( P K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & {a}_{i} \leq {x}_{i} \leq {b}_{i} \; \forall i
\end{aligned}$$ 
in order to solve this problrm with Projected gradient descent we need to take the derivative of the first and second term with respect to $x$. for the first term, we can take the advantage of matrix $P$ which is positive-definite matrix and can be wrritten as $P=C^{T}C$. the first term then can be treated as frobenius norm:

$$\begin{aligned}
 \operatorname{Tr} \left( {\left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right)}^{T} P \left( K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right) \right) = {\left\| K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) C \right\|}_{F}^{2}
\end{aligned}$$

then the gradient of the first term can be calculated as

$$\begin{aligned}
2{B}^{T} \operatorname{diag} \left( {(K A)}^{T} (K A) \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) CC^{T}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

if we consider the second term to be $T=- 2 \operatorname{Tr} \left( P K A \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) \right)$ we then have:

$dT=-2(PKA)^{T}:dX$ in which $dX=diag(Bx)$. using the properties of frobenius product we can write:

$dT=diag(-2(PKA)^{T}):di$ and $di=Bdx$ so:

$dT=B^{T}diag(-2A^{T}K^{T}(P)):dx$ and

$dT/dx=-2B^{T}diag(A^{T}K^{T}(P))$

overall the gradient of the above equation can be calculated as:

$$\begin{aligned}
2{B}^{T} \operatorname{diag} \left( {(K A)}^{T} (K A) \operatorname{diag} \left( B x \right) CC^{T}\right) -2B^{T}diag(A^{T}K^{T}P)
\end{aligned}$$

I appreciate if you can check and find out whether I am in a right direction or not?

Comment: I updated my answer with the direct gradient to your formulation, does it help making things simpler?

Comment: I think you forgot to include matrix $P$ in your problem statement above but that's no big deal since $P$ is the covariance matrix and is always semi-positive definite, it can be decomposed into $P=C^{T}C$. I will update my answer based on your update and what I said for the first term. but how about the second term? can I still use the same procedure as before (I mean using frobenius product properties)?

Comment: Well yes, the same trick. But now that I we have the explicit gradient the problem is easy.